# PDF viewer and annotator for iPad that can open views to the same document in different tabs

Tags: pdf-viewer, pdf-editor, ipad-app

I read math textbooks in PDF format. I read them on my iPad. My iPad can connect to the Internet via WiFi only, but I often read outdoors and in other places where there's no WiFi access.

Math textbooks often refer to results in other parts of the text, so in order not to lose track, I have open copies of the same textbook in several tabs: the first tab is open to the current page that I'm reading, the second tab is open to a result referred to in the first tab, the third tab is open to a result referred to in the second tab, etc. I find this setup incredibly helpful; I can't imagine reading math otherwise.

Math textbooks, even the best of them, are often riddled with errors. Whenever I encounter an error, I add an annotation to the PDF file indicating the correction. I use annotations for other purposes too, for instance to add an alternative explanation, or to add a reference to another textbook next to a result not proved in the current textbook. My textbooks are replete with annotations.

The problem is that all the annotations need to appear in the same document, but when I add annotations in different tabs, they are added to different copies of the document. I need a PDF reader that would allow me to have open simultaneously different views to the same document, rather than different copies of the document, so that no matter which tab I add an annotation in, the annotations will be added to one and the same document.

I also need to be able to do this while the iPad is offline, and the annotations need to be able to be saved while the iPad is offline.

There used to be an app that did all this: iAnnotate. However, several years ago they "upgraded" their app, and this feature disappeared. I sent them a request back then to restore this feature, but my request was denied.